# Selenium.webdriver trying to find a tab text vaue

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Hi I am using mocha and node js, and am trying to get selenium webdriver working. The app is a SPA.
All I want to do is get a particular tab, and then click on it.
I have loaded the html into the test OK. 
here is a snippet

```
<div id="Tabs">
   <ul>
       <li> <span> one </span></li>
       <li> <span> two </span></li>
        ...
        <li> <span> six </span></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

In my test.js I have this...

```
describe("MYHtml",function(){
  var driver;
  var tabs;
  driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();
  driver.get("file:///home/myhtml.html");
  test.after(function() {
    driver.quit();
});

before(function(done){
    driver.findElement(By.id("Tabs")).then(function(e){
        e.findElements(By.tagName("li")).then(function(b){
            console.log("before got tabs length " + b.length);
            tabs=b;
            done();
         });
     });
});
test.it("we have some tabs",function(done){
    assert.strictEqual(tabs.length,6);
    console.log("we have tabs " + tabs.length);
    done();
});
test.it("can find a tab name",function(done){
    var span;
    for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
        tabs[i].findElements(By.tagName("span"))       
                    .then(function(span){
                        console.log("Field??" + span.getText());
                        //return span;
                        done();
                    });
    }
}); )};
```

It passes the "we have some tabs"
but fails "can find a tab name"
    with this error

> 1 failing
>
> 1) MYHtml can find tab name:
>        TypeError: span.getText is not a function

I am trying to find the li  - e.g with the span text = 2
  so I can click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have resolved the promise with then and so that returns an array of span items. You should use getText() once the array is returned:

```
tabs[i].findElements(By.tagName("span"))       
            .then(function(spanArray){
                console.log('Found spans length:'+ spanArray.length);
                spanArray.forEach(function(nextElement) {
                   nextElement.getText().then(function(text) {
                      console.log('Text Found' + text);
                      // An if then check is required here so only
                      // one done is called.
                      if (/*---your condition here ---*/) {
                          done();
                      }
                   });
                }); 
            });
```

**EDIT** Code snippet revised above to cope with array and then process each element.

**Further Comment**
Adding @sferret comment regarding the XPATH approach.

Alternatively use XPATH, which can minimise the amount of code and processing needed:

```
var tab=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='Tabs']/ul/li/span[contains(.,'two')‌​]"));
```

However care should be taken as xpaths can quickly become a maintenance issue due to the span or div shifting in the example. You have to consider what may change in the page and act accordingly. Is a small amount of more JS code that will not change over time be more of burden than xPaths that in theory could change each week due to where the tab is placed within in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, sadly I am still getting the TypeError: tabs[i].findElements(...).getText is not a function

Comment: There are a few problems with this answer. One major problem is that there is no provision for indicating to Mocha when this asynchronous code is completely done (either by calling `done` or by returning a promise).

Comment: I returned the done() back to code, it was removed by mistake. Obviously returning to the original test the @sferret will need to decide what they require from an array of spans as the original suggested that a single value ('can find a tab name') may be needed.

Comment: @PeterS The way you've got it now, `done` would be called multiple times, which is bad. Mocha would raise an error due to this.

Comment: console.log  wrote out  "Found spans length:1 "  6 times . Test threw an error  Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.      The done wasn't called as it never got to the second console.log i.e "Text found"

Comment: @sferret That's right. That's why I wrote *would* in my earlier comment (it *would* call `done` multiple times but won't because of the problem you ran into).

Comment: Fixed it!    spanArray.forEach(function(nextElement) {
                        console.log("in span array " + nextElement);
                        nextElement.getText().then(function(p){
                            console.log("text is " + p);
                            if(p === text){
                                index=i;
                                done();
                            }
                        });
                    });

Comment: Glad it has got to a working solution, I was working on the basis of returning the code to stability rather than solving every problem. I would suggest perhaps not looking at every span and trying to locate the span in question via other means.

Comment: I needed to put a then function after nextElement.getText()  .to make it work Thanks for the help peter. I agree that this is pretty convoluted, probably xpath would be better

Comment: I made a further update, either Xpath - which isn't always recommended as it's not so maintainable or put in some extra class identifiers so that you can pick out the single element that you need - not always possible I know.

Comment: var tab=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='Tabs']/ul/li/span[contains(.,'two')]"));